# NLog class filter not working

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, nlog

I am having difficulty configuring NLog using class name filters.

```
<rules>
    <logger name="My.NameSpace.MyController" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
  </rules>
```

It doesn't log if I specify a fully qualified class name, but it does work if I specify `name="*"`

I am using Castle Windsor to set this up:

```
 Container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseNLog("NLog.config"));
```

Making this call in the MyController class

```
Logger = MvcApplication.Container.Resolve<ILogger>();
```

Is there anything else I have to specify to get this to work with the class rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are directly requesting an `ILogger` from the container (e.g with `Logger = MvcApplication.Container.Resolve<ILogger>();`) Windsor will always give you a default `ILogger` called `Default`.

You can change this default name with the `ToLog` method when configuring the `LoggingFacility`:

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseNLog("NLog.config")
                                             .ToLog("MyDefaultname"));
```

If you want to have the "current class logger" instead of a the default one then you need to let Windsor injects your `ILogger` instead of manually resolving it.

So if you using constructor injection:

```
public MyController
{
    private ILogger logger;

    public MyController(ILogger logger)
    {
         this.logger = logger;
    }
}
```

or property injection:

```
public MyController
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
}
```

Windsor will create an `ILogger` for you with the proper `My.NameSpace.MyController` name.

If you need more fine grained control of the logger names you can depend/resolve the `Castle.Core.Logging.ILoggerFactory` interface and you can create your own `ILogger`s with that.

Comment: So I would have to create an installer to have Windsor inject it, right?

Comment: No you don't need any additional installer. But are you talking about an Installer for the `ILogger` or for your `Contoller`? `ILogger` instances are automatically registered by the `LoggingFacility` and if your `MyController` is an MVC controller then it is probably already installed...

Comment: For some reason I can't get the ILogger to resolve if I just add an ILogger property on the controller.

Comment: What do you mean on "can't get the ILogger to resolve"? Is it `null`? Are you sure that your property is public and have a public setter? And the constructor injection version is working or not? Have you properly configured Castle for you MVC project using these steps: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-ASP-NET-MVC-3-application-To-be-Seen.ashx?

Comment: @TGH By the way the official documentation on MVC+Logging is also using property injection: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-Tutorial-Part-Five-Adding-logging-support.ashx so in theory it should just work.

Comment: @TGH We you solved the issue that your `ILogger` property is not correctly resolved?

Comment: Yes, the issue was related to incorrect configuration of the castle container.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Castle Windsor replaces your class with a proxy and logger name you set in config does not match actual instance type.

You could explicitly set log's name like

```
Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("My.NameSpace.MyController").
```

Extra tip: in many cases resolving logger using inversion of control does not bring many benefits and you can avoid doing this, otherwise you should tweak up you logger registration in Castle Windsor.

Answer (score 2):

If all classes under a given namespace use the same target, you can configure your rules like this:

```
<rules>
    <logger name="MyApp.Controllers.*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="fileTarget1" />
    <logger name="MyApp.AnotherNamespace.*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="fileTarget2" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="fileTarget3" />
</rules>
```

If you name your loggers with `GetType().FullName` in each controller (under `MyApp.Controllers`), the above configuration will write debug-level (and above) entries to `fileTarget1`, and error-level (and above) to both `fileTarget1` and `fileTarget3`.

Bottomline, the `*` wildcard is tremendously useful when you don't know (or care about) the exact names of the types that will use a given logging rule, so in your case this would work for all classes under `My.NameSpace`:

```
<logger name="My.NameSpace.*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
```

This works for me with Ninject, but as far as IoC is concerned it's just another dependency being injected, the container doesn't know it's a logging helper. So if Castle is generating the proxy AND you only need 1 target, you can probably get away with `Castle.*` as your filter.